# ifelse function on a vector

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using the ifelse function in order to obtain either a vector with NA if all the "value" of this vector are NA or a vector with all the values not equal to "NA_NA". In my example, I would like to obtain this results

```
 [1] "14_mter" "78_ONHY"
```

but I am obtaining this

```
[1] "14_mter"
```

my example:

```
vect=c("NA_NA", "14_mter", "78_ONHY")
out=ifelse(all(is.na(vec)), vec, vec[which(vec!="NA_NA")])
```

What is wrong in this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` is vectorized and its result is as long as the `test` argument. `all(is.na(vect))` is always just length one, hence the result. a regular if/else clause is fine here.

```
vect <- c("NA_NA", "14_mter", "78_ONHY")

if (all(is.na(vect))) {
  out <- vect 
} else {
  out <- vect[vect != "NA_NA"]
}
out
#> [1] "14_mter" "78_ONHY"
```

additional note: no need for the `which()` here

Comment: sure bug personally I like this one better. just personal preference

Answer (score 1):

The `ifelse` help file, referring to its three arguments `test`, `yes` and `no`,  says:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
> with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
> element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

so if the test has a length of 1, which is the case for the code in the question, then the result will also have length 1.  Instead try one of these.

**1)** Use `if` instead of `ifelse`.  `if` returns the value of the chosen leg so just assign that to `out`.

```
out <- if (all(is.na(vect))) vect else vect[which(vect != "NA_NA")]
```

**2)** The collapse package has an `allNA` function so a variation on (1) is:

```
library(collapse)
out <- if (allNA(vect)) vect else vect[which(vect != "NA_NA")]
```

**3)** Although not recommended if you really wanted to use `ifelse` it could be done by wrapping each leg in `list(...)` so that the condition and two legs all have the same length, i.e. 1.

```
out <- ifelse(all(is.na(vect)), list(vect), list(vect[which(vect != "NA_NA")])) |> 
  unlist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `NA`value is always the string `NA_NA`, this works:

```
grep("NA_NA", vect, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
[1] "14_mter" "78_ONHY"
```

While the pattern matches the `NA_NA` value, the `invert = TRUE` argument negates the match(es) and produces the unmatched values

Data:

```
vect=c("NA_NA", "14_mter", "78_ONHY")
```